# Saving Office Files to a Network Share

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-office-2010

Here is a link that pretty much describes exactly what is happening in my environment:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/5c4e725c-09ab-4326-a064-4d8747e01c0c

One of the participants recommends disabling SMB 2 on the Windows Server as a fix, but I'd rather not do that.

Has there ever been a real solution discovered for this problem?

Clients = Windows 7 Pro x64, Office Standard 2010 x64

File Share = Windows Server 2008 Enterprise x64 R2 SP 1

Comment: You should describe the issue here in case the link goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a permission issue or a connectivity one.

We have almost 1,000 Windows 7 clients constantly saving to a 2008 R2 Enterprise SMB share without issue.

If you want a more detailed answer, you're going to need to post relevent event log entries and/or procmon traces.

Comment: The issue isn't constant, it's intermittent. It also can't be permission related since the user has full access to the folders he's saving to. I would post event entries except I'm not really sure which events I"m looking for since I don't know what is causing the problem. The client's event log doesn't seem to have anything useful to say, nor does the Windows server log. I'll check again and report back.

Comment: A procmon trace of the issue occuring might shed some better light, then.